# Keeping excluded variables in summarise_at

Tags: r, summarize

I have a dataframe (this is just a subset of the full frame):

```
Depth <- seq(0, 2, 0.2)
cps <- sample(48000:52000, 11)
Al <- rnorm(11)
Si <- rnorm(11)
Fe <- rnorm(11)

df <- as_tibble(cbind(Depth, cps, Al, Si, Fe))
```

When I use mutate_at to perform a function for only chosen variables the final df still contains the variables I chose to exclude. So,

```
df_norm <- df %>%
mutate_at(vars(-c(Depth, cps)), ~abs(log(./df$cps)))
```

performs the function on Al, Si, Fe and df_norm is still a 11x5 tibble with Depth and cps being unchanged from df. However, when I do a similar move with summarise_at:

```
df_mean <- df %>%
summarise_at(vars(-c(Depth, cps)), mean)
```

the resulting dataframe is only 1x3 instead of 1x5 i.e. it removed Depth and cps instead of just ignoring them for the averaging.  Is there a different way I should be writing the vars argument to keep these?

**EDIT**
I would like my output to be a single observation(vector) with all 5 variables [1,5] at the median Depth value (in this case 1).

Comment: `summarise`. returns only row and per group.  If you exclude Depth, cps, what is your expected output.  One option is `mutate_at` `df %>% mutate_at(vars(-c(Depth, cps)), mean) `

Comment: `summarize` is made to perform aggregation functions. In other words, you create a single value from many values in a group. The mean of an entire column is a single value, or the mean of 5 groups of 20 data points is 5 values. A summary if you will. You haven't told it how to summarize/aggregate the missing columns so there is no way to keep them. If you want to keep the data the same length and number of columns then use mutate instead. If you want to summarize the columns then feel free to use another aggregation function like `first()` or something else within a summarize.

Comment: Thanks @AdamSampson for that explanation. I understand why my method wasn't giving me, or was even able to give me, the output I desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `devel` version of `dplyr`, we can use `summarise` with `across`, but still not sure what values we want for 'Depth', 'cps', so it is converted to a `list`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    summarise(across(Al:Fe, mean), across(Depth:cps, list))
# A tibble: 1 x 5
#     Al     Si     Fe Depth      cps       
#   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <list>     <list>    
#1 -0.438 -0.118 -0.590 <dbl [11]> <dbl [11]>
```

Or to get the `first` row

```
df %>%
    summarise(across(Al:Fe, mean), across(Depth:cps, first))
# A tibble: 1 x 5
#      Al     Si     Fe Depth   cps
#  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 -0.438 -0.118 -0.590     0 51432
```

Or to subset the `median` element of 'Depth'

```
df %>% 
    summarise(across(Al:Fe, mean), across(Depth:cps, ~ .[Depth == median(Depth)]))
# A tibble: 1 x 5
#      Al     Si     Fe Depth   cps
#   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 -0.438 -0.118 -0.590     1 51753
```

---

If we need the first row, then `mutate` and `slice` the first row

```
df %>%
    mutate_at(vars(-c(Depth, cps)), mean) %>%
    slice(1)
# A tibble: 1 x 5
#  Depth   cps     Al     Si     Fe
#  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     0 51432 -0.438 -0.118 -0.590
```

Or if it needs to be the `median` row

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-c(Depth, cps)), mean) %>%
  filter(Depth == median(Depth))
# A tibble: 1 x 5
# Depth   cps     Al     Si     Fe
#   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1 51753 -0.438 -0.118 -0.590
```

Comment: Thank you for that clarification @akrun; I have edited my original post to show my expected output. I think my only option would be to use ```mutate_at``` and then filter the median Depth value out (1) or use ```summarise_at``` and then stitch the necessary values of Depth and cps back to the vector. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: Thanks @akrun, all of these solutions worked. For my purposes, I will use the final option with ```filter(Depth == median(Depth))``` as it keeps the observations in the order I want.

Comment: @JJGabe I also updated with devel branch.  it is much more easier to return the `median` row

Comment: Great, thanks! By devel version, do you mean its currently under development? Does that mean that there could be some glitches or unexpected outputs when using the devel version?

Comment: @JJGabe yes, there would be some potential bugs.  I would test it on a container.  In the future versions, the `_at`, `_all`. would be superseded with `across`

Comment: I stuck with your final method using filter instead of across. I wasn't sure how to install/activate the devel version of dplyr. Also, I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and didn't want to add the devel repository for fear that it would update all packages that currently have a devel version. Would this happen? Or am I able to just install the devel dplyr?

Comment: @JJGabe I would also not disturb the current scenario, but will have a docker container and install the devel versiion of dplyr on it so it won't have any impact.  I usually does that for multiple versions or R or packages